# jQuery mouse position and calling click events of dynamically created elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

```
jQuery("body").dblclick(function(event){ 
    var x = event.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
    var y = event.pageY - this.offsetTop;
    jQuery("<div></div>").addClass("node").css("position","absolute")
        .css("top",x).css("left",y).bind("click",showOptions).appendTo("body");
        
    var showOptions = function()
    {
        alert("santa clara");
    }
});
```

I have two problems here one is that I am not able to get the mousePositions right. Other is that I am wishing to call function `showOptions` on click of dynamically created div that's not happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var x = event.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
var y = event.pageY - this.offsetTop;
```

The `document.body` has no `offsetLeft` and `offsetTop` as it is the page itself - it starts at `(0, 0)`. Don't you simply want `event.pageX` and `Y` perhaps? That will also correspond with `position: absolute` pixels.

Secondly, you define your`showOptions` function *after* you assign it to `.bind`. So it's not available *yet*.

I also added some tricks so that the code is a little more readable:

```
jQuery("body").dblclick(function(event){ 
    var showOptions = function()
    {
        alert("santa clara");
    };

    var x = event.pageX,
        y = event.pageY;

    jQuery("<div>").addClass("node")
                   .css({position: "absolute",
                         left:     x,
                         top:      y })
                   .click(showOptions)
                   .appendTo("body");

});
```

Comment: With this the function showOptions gets called. But the my Divs are not getting created at the place i am clicking on the screen.

Comment: @sushil bharwani: I overlooked a problems I made. You swapped `x` and `y` btw - `x` is for `left`. http://jsfiddle.net/pimvdb/5A44G/2/

Answer (score 2):

- Define `showOptions` first
- Use a function declaration rather than a function expression][1](http://kangax.github.com/nfe/#expr-vs-decl)
- There is [a simpler syntax for creating DOM elements](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery#jQuery2)

---

```
$('body').click(function (event)
{
    var x = event.pageX - this.offsetLeft,
        y = event.pageY - this.offsetTop;

   function showOptions()
   {
       alert('santa clara');
   }

   $('<div/>',
   {
       'class': 'node',
       css: {
           position: 'absolute',
           top: x,
           left: y
       },
       click: showOptions
   }).appendTo(this);
});
```

Comment: pimvdb seems to have figured out the problem with the mouse positions.

Comment: When I double-click on the textarea, I see 2 alerts. Chrome 13.

Comment: You need to use `.appendTo()`, not `.append()`. http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/5A44G/1/

Comment: well yea I put that in to check whether it goes in or not.. the new div doesnt get appended using the code which you posted here.. the div was created with the old code of the author.. but the event binding failed

Comment: wat abt the click event.. nothing happens when you click on the textbox

Comment: That's because of the inner `textarea` in the appended `div`. jQuery's shorthand element creation syntax won't work in that case, AFAIK. http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/qQz27/

Comment: can you guys help me figure out, How do i pass the reference of clicked div to the show options method.

Comment: @sushil this is a completely separate question. It is answered by the API docs, should you choose to read them: http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/

Comment: @matt my intial problem of not able to figure out mouse position is still remaining the answer by pimvdb is not working can you help me figure that out. Also should i post in a different question the problem with passing the parameter to showOptions function.